# Node.js express connection refused with /

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am using node.js and express and trying to create a simple application that answers to the route 'localhost/games' on port 3000

When I use the root index, 'localhost:3000' the application works fine. However, when I change this route to 'localhost/games:3000' I get connection refused with the exact same code.

Has anyone experienced this problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: should be localhost:3000/games, [port] comes after [host]

Comment: Try localhost:3000/games

Answer (score 2):

It does not have the right approach. You need to do (localhost:port/foo)

```
localhost:3000/games
```